# SSH to Server, Execute Command, and Maintain Connection

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

I want to  write a script that opens a terminal with different tabs, logon to a server using `ssh` in each tab and execute a command in each tab. For example: `htop`.

The below script opens a terminal with 4 tabs all logged in on the server. But if I try to add the `htop` command in the `cmd=` line it does not work anymore...

```
#bin/bash

tab="--tab"
cmd="bash -c 'ssh user@host';bash"
foo=""

for i in 1 2 3 4; do
      foo+=($tab -e "$cmd")         
done

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```

I have tried this...

```
cmd="bash -c 'ssh user@host htop';bash"
```

...because the `ssh --help` says that the syntax for `ssh` is:

> usage: ssh [user@]hostname [command]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In its simplest form:

```
ssh -t user@host "command; bash"
```

`-t` is the critical part here. It forces the host to allocate a virtual terminal to the process, which allows it to stay open.

If you just want to run htop on a load of servers, you can omit the `bash` at the end but that does mean if you quit htop, you'll drop back to a local terminal.

Comment: I tried cmd="bash -c 'ssh -t user@host htop';bash". It works but if I quit htop I drop back to local terminal and I don't want this happens

Comment: @Red Check your quotes - they're all over the place - you need to group htop and bash together so they're both run on the remote server. `bash -c 'ssh -t user@host "htop;bash"'` would be better but I don't see why you're trying to fry this thing in a bash wrapper in the first place. It isn't required - you're only running one command locally.

Comment: Thank you, now it works with cmd="ssh -t user@host htop;bash"

Comment: A good answer, but there must be something better to use than bash in order not to terminate.

Comment: @mc0e Depends what you want to do. This question is more about getting a useful shell after running your command. If you just want to pause, you could substitute `bash` for `read`.